# "'The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name" , when loading xml file usinf XDocument

Tags: xml, hex, linq-to-xml, system.xml

I have to read an XML file, but it has ':' in the first node.I am getting this error when I am trying to load the file using XDocument or XElement or xmldocument.I do not know how to resolve this issue.

```
string _filePath= @"C:\testfile.xml";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(_filePath);
```

"The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name. Line 1, position 6".

My XML document:

```
<?xml:stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="\\10.189.41.02\g$\XMLTest-Viewer.xsl"?>
<TestXml>
//More data here
 </TestXml>
```

If I remove the colon manually I can load the file successfully, is there a way to load the file with the ':' and without changing the XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct processing-instruction name is `xml-stylesheet`, not `xml:stylesheet`. Colons in processing instruction names are not allowed in well-formed XML - or to put it another way, you are trying to read a file that is not XML.

Comment: Thank you I will load the file stream as a string and do a replace and then load the xml file. Thank you .. I love your book XSLT 2.0 and XPATH 2.0 4th edition.